# Extensions not showing in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

i have installed two extensions

1. Bundler & Minifier
2. Sitecore Rocks

using extensions and updates in VS2017.

both were installed but i unable to find the icon or name in the tab in VS.

when i check in extensions and updates: both are in installed.
but not affected in visual studio

Any help ?

Comment: already had a look at this comment? https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/214#issuecomment-271271079

Comment: In my case, No duplicates found as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

- uninstall Rocks
- delete C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_c2d19173\privateregistry.bin and privateregistry.user.bin file (please backup them first)
- reinstall Rocks
- start Visual Studio and problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

1)Shutdown all VS instances

2)Backup and then delete the c:\users[username]\AppData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[hashid]\1033\devenv.ctm (note this file is hidden)

3)Restart VS